# ElasticSearch Post call within Angular7 is throwing 400 bad error

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, datatable, angular-material, angular-datatables

I am trying to make elasticSearch Post call within Angular 7 but it is throwing 400 bad error.

```
public elasticSearch<T>(): Observable<ElasticModel<T>> {
  const reqBody = {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": {
          "match": {
            "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  return this.http.get<ElasticResponseData<T>>(`${this.apiUri}/_search/query?indexName=` + 1 + `&query=` + JSON.stringify(reqBody) + `&size=` + 2 + `&from=` + (page - 1) * size);
  // return this.http.get<ElasticResponseData<T>>(`${this.apiUri}/_search`);
}
```

I am able to make successful call though when not passing any params and making regular `get call`

```
return this.http.get<ElasticResponseData<T>>(`${this.apiUri}/_search`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON Query you are sending is meant to be sent in the **body** of the HTTP request.  You are sending it through the **URL**

You have two options:

1. Use the URI Search DSL [found here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html).  This has a more limited set of query options, but it does not require a request body
2. Modify your Angular code to send the JSON in the actual body of the request.  According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164149/angular-httpclient-get-method-with-body), HttpClient library does not have an easy way to do this for GET requests.  You may have to write custom code for this.