# How to pass request model to get API on Angular 7/8?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I have Get Api to get users data where I can pass a request model to search users list based on request model.
Its working fine on Postman but while I am trying to implement same in Angular 7 and 8 its not working.

Please guide me how can I implement.

My implementation is as below

**Postman**

```
    URL = http://localhost:64888/api/Users/SearchUsers     
    Header : Content-Type = application/json

    Body = 
    {
        "firstname" : "value",
        "lastname" : "value",
        "emailid" : "value",
        "usertype" : "value",
    }
```

**Postman Result:** Its working fine and gives users list

**Request Model**

```
export class UserRequest {  
     firstname : string;
     lastname : string;
    emailid : string;
    usertype : string;
    }
```

**User Service**

```
    export class UserService {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      SearchUsers(requestParam : UserRequest) : Observable<any>{  

        const httpOptions = {
          headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization' : 'Bearer Tokenvalue'
          },
          params: requestParam
        };

        return this.http.get("http://localhost:64888/api/Users/SearchUsers", httpOptions); 
      }
    }
```

**User Component**

```
   export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor(private userService : UserService) { }

     ngOnInit() {

       var requestParam : UserRequest;
       requestParam.firstname = "r";
       requestParam.lastname = "";
       requestParam.emailid = "";
       requestParam.usertype = "user";

       this.userService.SearchUsers(requestParam)
         .subscribe( 
           data => {
             console.log(data);
           }
          )
     }
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz or fiddle for the same

Comment: You are very likely having a CORS issue here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send param in body then use POST request, Mostly In GET request param is being sent in url 
please see this link
[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164149/angular-httpclient-get-method-with-body)

convert your request like this

```
 SearchUsers(requestParam : UserRequest) : Observable<any>{  

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer Tokenvalue'
      }
    };

    return this.http.get("http://localhost:64888/api/Users/SearchUsers?firstname=value&lastname=value&emailid=value&userid=value", httpOptions); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for response but I don't want to use the post request to get data. As it is working in postman and .net code then definitely it should work in Angular as well, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and replace with your code in UserService

```
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  SearchUsers(requestParam : UserRequest) : Observable<any>{  

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer Tokenvalue'
      },
    };

    return this.http.get("http://localhost:64888/api/Users/SearchUsers+"?firstname="+requestParam.firstname+"&lastname="+requestParam+"&emailid="+requestParam.emailid +"&usertype="+requestParam.usertype ", httpOptions); 
  }
}
```

Comment: praful jain, first please understand the question.